# Python Pandas split column into two columns based on last element and remaining elements

Tags: python, regex, pandas, split

I want to split my column called `period` into new two columns. In one new column I want to return the last element in `period` and second new column is all the remaining elements.

**My dataframe looks this with dummy data:**

```
import pandas as pd 

d = {'period': ['May \'20 Base',
                'June \'20 Peaks',
                'Friday Base',
                '24/07/2020 XY1+XY2',
                '01-02 August \'20 Peaks',
                'June \'20 XY1+XY2+XY3']
    }

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

**Output desired:**

```
                  period              colA         colB
0            May '20 Base           May '20         Base
1          June '20 Peaks          June '20        Peaks
2             Friday Base            Friday         Base
3      24/07/2020 XY1+XY2        24/07/2020      XY1+XY2
4  01-02 August '20 Peaks  01-02 August '20        Peaks
5    June '20 XY1+XY2+XY3          June '20  XY1+XY2+XY3
```

**My try:**

I can return the last element in `period` but I can't return all the remaining elements which varies between 1-3 elements.

```
df['colB'] = df.period.str.split().str[-1]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following pattern:

```
pat = '^(?P<colA>.*) (?P<colB>\S+)$'
df.join(df.period.str.extract(pat))
```

Output:

```
                   period              colA         colB
0            May '20 Base           May '20         Base
1          June '20 Peaks          June '20        Peaks
2             Friday Base            Friday         Base
3      24/07/2020 XY1+XY2        24/07/2020      XY1+XY2
4  01-02 August '20 Peaks  01-02 August '20        Peaks
5    June '20 XY1+XY2+XY3          June '20  XY1+XY2+XY3
```

Comment: Can you quickly explain why it's extract and not split? Also why do you use join?

Comment: I just feel like using `extract` in the sense that it captures more logic with `regex`. You can use `rsplit` like this: `df.period.str.rsplit(' ', n=1, expand=True)`. Regard `join`, it's a convenient way to concatenate the result into the original data.

Answer (score 2):

You may use

```
(.+)\s+(\S+)$
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/GpPQ7O/1/).